# More performant way of sorting by selected first

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting

I have a table and a map above that contains markers that relate to the table rows below. When a user selects items on the map above it highlights the matching rows then moves those rows to the top of the table but sorts by the user's sorting setting.

For example, if you had this *raw* data (not displayed data):

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'Z'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Y'},
  {id: 3, name: 'X'},
  {id: 4, name: 'W'}
]
```

Then the user selects `id: 1` and `id: 3` on the map and has it sorted by `name`. The data becomes:

```
[
  {id: 3, name: 'X'}, // selected
  {id: 1, name: 'Z'}, // selected
  {id: 4, name: 'W'}, // not selected
  {id: 2, name: 'Y'}  // not selected
]
```

There's some data sets with 10,000+ rows and I'm worried this is locking up too long when they select the items because of the 2 filters + concat. Is there a way to do this in one pass or just a way to prevent the browser from locking while it's doing this?

```
  var selectedRows = rows.filter(function (row) {
    return selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(row.id) !== -1
  });

  var nonSelectedRows = rows.filter(function (row) {
    return selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(row.id) == -1
  });

  var allRows = selectedRows.concat(nonSelectedRows);

  myTable.updateRowSort(allRows);
```

Comment: Why not just sort of original array?

Comment: How? `rows` is the array. I tried a bunch of compare methods, but I couldn't figure out how to get any of them to keep the original sort order but just hoist selected rows up top

Comment: Maybe add a boolean key and then redefine the javascript "sort" function.

Comment: Are you using pagination? Ideally, you would operate on all 10,000 rows if necessary, but only introduce DOM manipulation to visible elements. DOM manipulation and associated repainting is what will bottleneck your app.

Comment: @sean9999 we only _display_ 200 rows at a time and as you scroll down and hit our invisible buffer we load the next "cluster" of rows and remove the top "cluster" of rows so you only ever have 200 rows of the DOM.

Comment: is [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) an option for you?

Comment: @code_monk haven't really thought about it but that might speed it up a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reduce. In the callback function, it checks for whether the row was selected or not and pushes it to the appropriate array in the result object. You do this in one pass and then concat the arrays in the last step.

```
var result = rows.reduce((result, row) => {
  selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(row.id) !== -1 ? result.selected.push(row) : result.notSelected.push(row);
  return result;
}, {
  selected: [],
  notSelected: []
});

result.selected.concat(result.notSelected);
```

I'm also a big fan of lodash and here's the lodash implementation. I first pass the array to the chain function which basically wraps it around a lodash wrapper which enables chaining of lodash functions. I then pass the array through my reduce function, similar to what I did above with `Array.prototype.reduce`, but this time the result's initial value is an array of two arrays: the first array is meant for selected rows while the second is for non-selected rows. I then use `_.flatten` to flatten the nested array so now we have an array of objects instead of an array of arrays. I call value to unwrap the lodash wrapper and get my finally value which is an array of rows.

```
/**
 * in the reduce function, the initial value of the 
 * result is an array of two arrays. 
 * the first array is for selected items.
 * the second array is for non-selected items.
 */
var newArray = _.chain(rows)
  .reduce((result, row) => {
    selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(row.id) !== -1 ? result[0].push(row) : result[1].push(row);
    return result;
  }, [ [], [] ])
  .flatten()
  .value();
```

Comment: your reduce seems to be about 2.5x faster. Getting ~3.6ms on a dataset with 12K rows to run the reduce vs the 2 filters. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-sorting every time the user updates, keep two persistent arrays. One for selected items, and one for items that are not selected. When a user selects an item, splice it out of the not selected items array, and push it into the selected items array. Then update the final array by concatenating those two arrays.

You might end up with something along these lines:

```
  var selectedItem = nonSelectedItems.splice(selectedItemIndex, 1);

  selectedItems.push(selectedItem);

  var allRows = selectedRows.concat(nonSelectedRows);

  myTable.updateRowSort(allRows);
```

...where selectedItems and nonSelectedItems are arrays that live outside of the scope of whatever event handler is called to update the order when a user selects something.

Answer (score 0):

To keep original index you will need to add .index property to each record:

```
var indexed = rs.map( function(el,index) { el.index = index; return el; } );
```

And then sorting is trivial:

```
var sorted = indexed.sort(function(a,b) {
  var asel = selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(a.id) !== -1;
  var bsel = selectedMarkerIds.indexOf(b.id) !== -1; 

  if( asel && bsel )
    return a.name < b.name ? -1:1;

  if( asel ) return -1;
  if( bsel ) return +1;

  // both records are in not selected set
  return a.index - b.index;
});
```

Comment: i'd need to update that index whenever the sort changed (search, column header click, etc), correct?

Comment: No. That index maintains original "not sorted" ordering. You just need to call that indexed.sort part when selectedMarkerIds is changed.

Comment: Ah ok. The user can sort/filter however they want so in my example above by a `name` column. By default its just sorted by the index it was added in the database (1st code block). It displays, they click the `name` column header. Now it's sorted by the `name`. As they select markers it'd need to be sorted by the `name` (alphabetical) but in two categories of selected and not selected (2nd code block). I think your solution would work but the map would need to happen on every sort and filter.

Comment: That comparator function sorts 1) selected group alphabetically by name. 2) non selected group is not sorted - records there are in original  order.

Comment: To have first group non-sorted modify comparator to this:
`if( asel && bsel )
    return a.index - b.index;`

Answer (score 0):

Use one more variable selected-index = 0 -  increment on each select. Use `unshift` to push @top filter or use splice to push @ `selected-index`, if u want to use the sorted position iterate `0 to selected-index` &push using `splice`